# Rails 3 - Send Mails, Request request progress using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, email

i want to use Rails 3 to send a relatively large amount of emails to a couple of recipients. The email functionality is basically implemented, so that's not the matter here.

My problem is that this amount of emails is sent relatively slow. So i want to give the user a little feedback using AJAX. Now this feedback should be unique for each user of course. My first thought was to create a helper class which sends these mails using a thread and a method for requesting the progress. Problem is, how can I make this functionality unique to each user per session?
I'm new to Rails and have absolutely no idea, I think some kind of Stateful Session Bean (like EJB) should make it. Does Rails or one of its addons offer something like that?

Sorry for my english, it's a bit rusty. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this help [sidekiq_mailer](https://github.com/andersondias/sidekiq_mailer)

this adds to your ActionMailer classes the ability to send mails asynchronously.